# Can you spend a Power Point to add a power to a premade Array of Powers?

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

We have finally played our first session in Mutants and Masterminds 3e, a premade module that at the end of it, offered to each of my players 3 Power Points to spend and power up their characters. My question is about the manner that they are going to spend these points:

Can they spend one point to add a power to a premade Array of Powers, or is this only available in the character creation step? (The 1 point cost for adding a new Alternate Power to an array).

If the answer is that they cannot add a new effect to a premade array, do they have to spend full cost on the new power?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spending points after character creation works in the same way as during character creation. From the "Hero Advancement & Improvement" section (emphasis mine):

> Players spend power points on new or improved traits for their heroes **just the same as spending them to create a hero**. So if your hero has a power costing 2 points per rank, and you want to improve it by 1 rank, spend 2 of your earned power points to do so.

This means they can naturally spend 1 point to add a new power to an array as usual.

Answer (score 3):

They can absolutely do that. There is nothing different in the process of leveling up from the process character creation, other than the amount of points to distribute.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly is possible to spend new points to further expand an array. M&M doesn't have a mechanic of preventing players from spending points a certain way outside of character creation.

What is necessary though, is GM oversight with regard to the type of power that is added to the array, especially to avoid serious min-maxing. The new power really ought to be something that makes sense as an alternate use of the same ability.

Make sure to note that there is an action economy to switching around power arrays. As well, changing the active power undoes any current effects. If you have an affliction as part of an array, switching from the affliction causes the target to cease suffering from it.

It can get a bit tricky, especially with concepts like magic ("All my spells are just Alternate Powers GM!" followed by a 200 point power that represents total mastery over existence).

Comment: `If you have an affliction as part of an array, switching from the affliction causes the target to cease suffering from it.`
Is it truly so? I always made it up depending on the power descriptor, like... If I shot you a venomous dart and change power to gatling gun, you are still poisoned. But if I was restraining you with my tentacles and then use them for attack, you are no longer restrained.
Have I been playing wrong?

Comment: @Helwar This looks like a different question altogether, you should post it!

Comment: Agreed that the Affliction effects don't go away on a switch, any more than Damage goes away when you switch.

Comment: I guess, only effects that need to be concentrated on, should be dismissed on effect change.